# Apache Beam ValueError: Group by key: Unsafe trigger: `AfterProcessingTime(delay=60)` may lose data. Reason: MAY_FINISH

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I'm getting an error while applying windowing and triggers before writing my data to BigQuery.
Following is my piece of code:

```html
class GroupMessagesByFixedWindowsForBigquery(PTransform):

    def __init__(self, windowSize, numShards):
        self.windowSize = int(windowSize * 60)
        self.numShards = numShards

    def expand(self, pcoll):
        return (
            pcoll
            | "Window into fixed intervals" >> WindowInto(GlobalWindows() ,trigger=AfterProcessingTime(1 * 60), accumulation_mode=AccumulationMode.DISCARDING)#,trigger=AfterProcessingTime(10 * 60), accumulation_mode=AccumulationMode.DISCARDING)
            | "Add timestamp to windowed elements" >> ParDo(decodeMessage())
            | "print" >> beam.Map(print)
            # Assign a random key to each windowed element based on the number of shards.
            | "Add key" >> WithKeys(lambda _: random.randint(0, self.num_shards - 1))
            # Group windowed elements by key. All the elements in the same window must fit
            # memory for this. If not, you need to use `beam.util.BatchElements`.
            | "Group by key" >> GroupByKey()
        )



class decodeMessage(DoFn):
    def decode_base64(self,element, publish_time=DoFn.TimestampParam):
        payload = dict()
        data = base64.b64encode(element.data)
        attributes_input = (json.dumps(element.attributes)).encode('utf-8')
        attributes = base64.b64encode(attributes_input)
        messageKey = str(element.message_id)
        publishTime = element.publish_time
        
        payload['et'] = publishTime
        payload['data'] = data
        payload['attr'] = attributes
        payload['key'] = messageKey
        yield (payload)
        
 ( demo  
                    | "Window Bigquery Data" + input_subscription >> GroupMessagesByFixedWindowsForBigquery(windowSize = 60,numShards = 1)
                    | "Write to BigQuery Table"  + input_subscription  >> io.WriteToBigQuery('{0}:{1}'.format(project_name, dest_table_id),
                                                                            schema=schema, write_disposition=io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_APPEND, create_disposition = io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED)
            )
```

Can someone help me to get and idea and how to solve the following problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a pipeline that would trigger **once** after 60 seconds and will never fire again. Hence you may lose data.

The fix probably is to use a repeatedly firing trigger or to use FixedWindows instead of GlobalWindow.

For example: `trigger=Repeatedly(AfterProcessingTime(1 * 60))`